# Changed template name and now wp_list_comments() is not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had to change the template folder name because it had a space it in. That messed with my HTML validity.

So 'Panda Productions' -->became--> 'PandaProductions'

Now `wp_list_comments();` doesn't work. Comments aren't showing up.

When I changed the name back, it worked again.

Comment: Do a global search for 'Panda Productions' in your template files. Maybe the folder name is hardcoded somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in `single.php` (or in other pages optionally) `WordPress` adds `comment template` depending on function call of [comments_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template), which means the comment template is a separate file and by calling this function (mentioned above) we add comment template in files/pages like `single.php`, this functions accepts optional parameters and one parameter is being used as a filename to load the template file, if a filename is supplied with the function then it loads that file as the comment template, otherwise it looks for `/comments.php` file in the same folder by default. You can see the source of this function [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L823).

So, I think, the problem is that, this function `(comments_template()`) is called in your `single.php` with the folder path/name and that's why it's not being loaded after you change the folder name. If you search for this function call then you may find the path and filename that used in your theme and you can modify those as well.